# How do you stop sound playback in Garry's Mod?

Tags: garrys-mod

**in this case, i want to stop function that's running**

**Example**

```
local function X()
    Play("Hello.mp3")
end
```

I want new function(let's call it Function Y) to stop function X while it still play the sound

Any ideas?!

Comment: Are you trying to stop sound playback from within Lua? If so, what sound library/engine do you use? Stopping the execution of random functions isn't really a language feature (as the language isn't multi-threaded, as far as I'm aware)

Comment: yes, i use source engine (i make addon for garry'smod)

Comment: here's command list https://wiki.garrysmod.com

Answer (score 0):

Instead of relying on [`surface.PlaySound()`](http://wiki.garrysmod.com/page/surface/PlaySound) which provides no way to cancel sound playback, use [`CreateSound`](http://wiki.garrysmod.com/page/Global/CreateSound) which returns a sound object.

You can start/stop the playback with the following client-side code:

```
sound = CreateSound(game.GetWorld(), "Hello.mp3")
sound:Play()
sound:Stop()
```